# proving algebraic expression involving rational function

Tags: sequences-and-series

If $$^nJ_r = \frac{(1-x^n)(1-x^{n-1})(1-x^{n-2})\cdots (1-x^{n-r+1})}{(1-x)(1-x^2)(1-x^3)\cdots (1-x^r)}$$

then prove that $\displaystyle ^nJ_{n-r}=^nJ_{r}$

what i try

$$^nJ_{n-r} = \frac{(1-x^n)(1-x^{n-1})(1-x^{n-2})\cdots (1-x^{r+1})}{(1-x)(1-x^2)(1-x^3)\cdots (1-x^{n-r})}$$

dod not kow how do i solve it help me please

Comment: Set them equal and clear denominators.  You get a true statement.  Now just do the steps in reverse.

Comment: why not try some concrete examples, like $n=10, r=3$, to see what's going on?

Comment: It might help to write out explicitly a (slightly) non-trivial example, say ${}^7 J_3$ and see where the cancellations come from.

Comment: did not understand fully please explain me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\displaystyle f(r)=(1-x)(1-x^2)(1-x^3)\cdots\cdots (1-x^r).$

Then $\displaystyle ^nJ_{r}=\frac{(1-x^n)(1-x^{n-1})\cdots (1-x^{n-r+1})\cdots (1-x^{n-r})(1-x^{n-r-1})\cdots (1-x)}{(1-x)(1-x^2)\cdots (1-x^{n-r})}\cdots \times \frac{1}{(1-x)(1-x^2)\cdots (1-x^{n-r})}.$

$$\displaystyle ^nJ_{r}=\frac{f(n)}{f(r)\cdot f(n-r)}.$$

$$ ^nJ_{r}=^nJ_{n-r}.$$